# Lambda loses captured value

Tags: c++, lambda

I cannot understand why the captured value is lost. I understand that it is connected with an out of scope or copying of an object of LambdaWrapper. But what exactly happens? If LambdaWrapper(100) leaves the scope in Add and reference to __value loses, then why there is no same to LambdaWrapper(300).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class LambdaWrapper {
public:
    LambdaWrapper(double new_value): __value (new_value) {
        cout << "constructed with " << __value << endl;
        __func = [this](){ cout << __value << endl;};
    }
    void call() const { __func(); }
private:
    double __value;
    function<void(void)> __func;
};

class LambdaContainer {
public:
    void Add(double value) {
        LambdaWrapper w(value); //out of scope
        parts.push_back(w);
    }

    void Add(LambdaWrapper w) // passed as value
    {
        parts.push_back(w);
    }

    void call() const {
        for (const auto& part : parts)
                part.call();
    }
private:
    vector<LambdaWrapper> parts;
};

int main() {
    LambdaContainer c;
    c.Add(100);

    LambdaWrapper w(200);
    c.Add(w);

    c.Add( LambdaWrapper(300) ); //LambdaWrapper(300) will out of scope too

    cout << "==============" << endl;
    c.call();

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

> ```
> constructed with 100
> constructed with 200
> constructed with 300
> ==============
> 6.95168e-308 <<< WHY?
> 200
> 300
> ```

Comment: Consider what happens when a `LambdaWrapper` gets copied. Since there is no user-defined copy constructor, the `__func` member is an exact copy of the `__func` being copied - and that has captured the `this` pointer from an object that, when you call `c.call()` no longer exists. The behaviour is therefore undefined.  Additionally: get out of the habit of using identifiers with a double-underscore prefix, like `__func` - such identifiers are reserved to the implementation - creating them yourself also causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why works with 300? Accidentally, because memory was not rewritten yet? Thanks for the hint about double-underscore prefix - I thought it it is accepted for private members.

Comment: @EzR1d3r single underscores are accepted in local.. capitalized  both and double underscores aren't allowed anywhere (I may forget something), including preprocessor macro (quick gcc example - __reserved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this question is asking what happens, rather than "Is it ok", so in this case (usually) `gdb` is your friend, modifying the program to print the address of this during construction, this inside __func and the actual address of the object in the container we see:
(addresses varies, but distances and concepts should remain the same)

```
# During constructors and captured value:
0x7fffffffda80 <- LambdaWrapper(100)
0x7fffffffdb00 <- LambdaWrapper(200)
0x7fffffffdb60 <- LambdaWrapper(300)
# Actual address of data stored in the container:
0x6170c0 <- LambdaWrapper(100)
0x6170e8 <- LambdaWrapper(200)
0x617110 <- LambdaWrapper(300)
```

There is a huge value difference, this is because the creation happens on the **stack**, while the vector allocates data with `new` on the **heap**.

From `gdb` calling `info proc mappings` we obtain the memory addresses list:

```
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
            0x400000           0x404000     0x4000        0x0 /[...]/LambdaOutOfScope/a.out
            0x603000           0x604000     0x1000     0x3000 /[...]/LambdaOutOfScope/a.out
            0x604000           0x605000     0x1000     0x4000 /[...]/LambdaOutOfScope/a.out
            0x605000           0x637000    0x32000        0x0 [heap]

[...]

      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0 [vsyscall]
```

But this does not answer *why* only the 100 is changed.
The answer to the problem resides in the **stack frames**:
each function call has a local (usually *small*) variable space for static variables (those without `new` for simplicity).

If we check the stack info with `info frame` we see that:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdbb0:
 rip = 0x400deb in main (main.cpp:75); saved rip = 0x7ffff7495830
 source language c++.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdba0, args: 
 Locals at **0x7fffffffdba0**, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdbb0
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7fffffffdb98, rbp at 0x7fffffffdba0, rip at 0x7fffffffdba8
```

Inside main, so the 100 stays **out** of this frame, because it **is not constructed in main** but in `Add`, to check, when inside Add we get:

```
(gdb) info frame 1
Stack frame at 0x1:
 rip = 0x0; saved rip = <not saved>
 Outermost frame: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffdac8, args: 
 Locals at **0x7fffffffdac8**, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdad8
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0x7fffffffdad0
```

So the corruption happens when we call another function, but **since the elements allocated in main are local they are preserved**, if you put a `c.Add(400);` after the 300 you'll see it corrupted too (even if constructed after).

**NOTE**: I hope to have covered all, but gdb usage in detail, there are plenty of guides on the internet.

Comment: LambdaWrapper(300) is not overwritten by any local variable when call is used, but if you force another variable **completely disjoint** wrt that it can be overwritten: { c.Add( LambdaWrapper(300) ); } { string x = "What?"; cout << x << endl; }.

Comment: This is interpretation of optimized return which  is incorrect if mapped back to source code. It is what happens from hardware point, but not from language's abstraction point. There is no corruption or IB, just a dangling pointer to temporal object.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Exactly, this is merely the current gcc behavior, from a language prospective it is indeed undefined behavior

Answer (score 2):

Why one need to do this, if lambda is already a wrapper like that? To preserve capture? You're doing opposite of that.

Your closure, created within `Add(double)` method, captures value of `this` , which points at object for which that method was called. And that object "dies" when method goes out of scope. Value of that pointer stays incorrect, it's a dangling pointer to a local or temporal object. Same would happen with other objects too because of this design.

```
LambdaWrapper(const LambdaWrapper &obj) {
        __value = obj.__value;
        __func = [this](){cout << __value << endl;};
    }
```

This constructor works, because it creates new lambda with new `this` value for instance which would persist. Lambda is nothing more but syntax sugar for an instance of class with pointer field (presumably `__this`) which stores value of `this` and contains `void operator() () {cout << __this->__value << endl;};`

Any call to `Add(double)` would result in dangling pointer and UB, call with temporal object results in UB too, because that object would not be bound with const reference (which works only in local anyway), so it's a dangling pointer too. The method accepts wrapper by value, which results in another step of copy.

That design is suboptimal because every time a new object is created. You would not need a copy constructor if you'll capture just the value.

PS. As an illustration to nature of lambda closures, GCC even had a bug\flaw in past, where members of lambda are accessible from outside, because they weren't private members.

Answer (score 1):

By all means pay attention to @Peter's comment.

If you really want a solution, define the copy c'tor of LambdaWrapper yourself so that it would capture the `this` of the source object.

```
class LambdaWrapper
{
public:
    LambdaWrapper(double new_value): __value (new_value)
    {
        cout << "constructed with " << __value << endl;
        __func = [this](){ cout << __value << endl;};
    }
    LambdaWrapper(const LambdaWrapper &obj) {
        __value = obj.__value;
        __func = [this](){cout << __value << endl;};
    }
    void call() const { __func(); }
private:
    double __value;
    function<void(void)> __func;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I know what it works with copy constructor, I wanted to understand what occurs.

Comment: @EzR1d3r see my explanation, this is misticlly changing inside of closure, it would be passed as part of functor  object created by lamba.